# .NET not loading specific version of dependency

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to load the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll (13.0.x.x) when running my project (MyBinary.exe). My production directory structure looks like this:

```
Base/MyBinary.exe - The executable I run
Base/Newtonsoft.Json.dll - old version 6.0.x.x, built for .NET Framework 4
Base/<subdirectory>/Newtonsoft.Json.dll - new version 13.0.x.x, build for .NET standard 2.0
```

I cannot get rid of the `Base/Newtonsoft.Json.dll` as other parts of the system depend on this older version. I want my particular binary to only use the latest version.

Whenever I run my process, it always loads the older version of Newtonsoft from the Base directory:
[image]

My project is a .NET 8.0 project. It attempts to load in the 6.0.x.x built for framework. I verified that in my project dependencies. The correct version is being used during compile time:

[image]

I have already tried:

1. Creating an app.config file to leverage app.config's bindingredirect:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

This did nothing. It still loaded the older version during runtime.

2. Used the `<Reference>` tag in csproj to reference a specific version.

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0">
            <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
            <HintPath>D:\CTELibraries\Libraries\Google\1.67\net8.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The weird thing here is that this reference refuses to load in any of my csproj libaries:
[image]
[image]

But it loads fine in my .NET c++/CLI intermediate bridge library:

[image]
[image]

And when I remove the version details in the csproj (but keep the hintpath). It loads fine, but does not honor the hint path:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
            <HintPath>D:\CTELibrary\Libraries\Google\1.67\net8.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
```

[image]
[image]

3. The only thing that has worked is using `Assembly.Load()` in the code with the `Base/<subdirectory>/Newtonsoft.Json.dll` path. I would rather avoid using this method as I want to figure out why I can't just use the correct version to be used during compile time.